# svn log and blame of svn:externals

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm using both TortoiseSVN and svn clinet from Linux prompt.

In our project, I have a directory with svn:external property. I'm trying to dig svn history to see who and when did the change. I don't find a way to see log of properties of the directory or blame/annotate the directory svn properties?

How can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the history of a file/folder property in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230389/how-do-you-get-the-history-of-a-file-folder-property-in-svn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command:

```
$ svn log -v --diff --depth=empty $dir
```

On the directory that contains the `svn:externals` property you're interested in. You'll see an output like this:

```
r154474 | dweintraub | 2012-11-14 09:50:20 -0500 (Wed, 14 Nov 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/ivy/TC-Common-All

Some utterly useless comment

Index: .
===================================================================
--- .   (revision 154473)
+++ .   (revision 154474)

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:externals
## -1 +1 ##
-^/trunk/ivy.dir ivy.dir
+^/branches/ivy/ivy.dir ivy.dir
```

Comment: Works. But it also display regular commits (i.e. adds/removes of files). My project is too big and it took quit a lot of time to reach relevant commit. Can the command be optimized?

Comment: You could write a script to first do a `svn log` on the directory, and then pull out those entries where you see the regex `^\s+M\s+$directory_name$`. That will quickly give you all of the revisions where the directory was modified in some way. Since it's a directory, some property must have changed on it. Then, you could do a `svn log --diff -v --depth=empty` on just those revisions. A bit more complex than a simple pipeline, but if you're half decent at Perl or Python, it shouldn't take you too long to write such a script.

Comment: Build off of David's suggestion, if you want to limit it to just the externals, key off of the "Modified: svn:externals comment." I'm using grep & tee, which you can get with the [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) if you're on Windows. Tee could be replaced with >> redirect. In this I tell it to give me the log (you could limit to a range of revs) then search for the expression "Modified: svn:externals" and grab 7 lines `B`efore and 2 `A`fter, which gives the info I need.
`svn log -v --diff --depth=empty . | grep -B 7 -A 2 -e"Modified: svn:externals" | tee externalChanges.log`

Comment: What version of subversion is this working on: is it working on subversion version prior to 1.7?  Im trying it on a repo that uses svn 1.6.xx and that does not seem to work.