# svn blame properties with command line svn

Tags: svn, properties, blame

I am trying to get an svn blame out of svn for the svn properties. I expected there would be something like:

```
svn blame --prop .
```

but I cannot find such an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the history of a file/folder property in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230389/how-do-you-get-the-history-of-a-file-folder-property-in-svn)

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Revision properties are not versioned in Apache Subversion. In other words, you can't run [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) against revision property.

From ["SVNBook | Properties"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html):

> The main difference is that **revision properties are not versioned**. In
>   other words, if you change the value of, or delete, a revision
>   property, there's no way, within the scope of Subversion's
>   functionality, to recover the previous value.

Comment: But afaik normal properties are versioned. Like svn:externals svn:ignore etc.

Comment: @Veda see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230389/how-do-you-get-the-history-of-a-file-folder-property-in-svn